# How to Implementing Child Row Toggle Buttons in DataTables

Tags: node.js, typescript, datatables

I am currently implementing DataTables (https://datatables.net/) in a project using Nuxt3 and TypeScript. My goal is to add a child row toggle button to each data item. When this toggle button is clicked, I would like to display multiple new buttons in the area of the sub-row. I have searched for a solution but have not been able to find one, and I am seeking assistance. Could anyone provide advice on how to approach this setup?

Thank you for your help.

Here is my source code:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import DataTable from 'datatables.net-vue3';
import DataTablesCore from 'datatables.net-bs5';

DataTable.use(DataTablesCore);

const columns = [
  { data: 'name' },
  { data: 'position' },
  { data: 'office' },
  { data: 'extn' },
  { data: 'start_date' },
  { data: 'salary' },
];

const data = [
{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Tiger Nixon",
        "position": "System Architect",
        "salary": "$320,800",
        "start_date": "2011/04/25",
        "office": "Edinburgh",
        "extn": "5421"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Garrett Winters",
        "position": "Accountant",
        "salary": "$170,750",
        "start_date": "2011/07/25",
        "office": "Tokyo",
        "extn": "8422"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Ashton Cox",
        "position": "Junior Technical Author",
        "salary": "$86,000",
        "start_date": "2009/01/12",
        "office": "San Francisco",
        "extn": "1562"
      }
]
</script>

<template>
  <div class="container">
   
    <DataTable
      :columns="columns"
      :data="data"
      class="table table-hover table-striped"
      width="100%"
    >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Extn.</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </DataTable>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'datatables.net-bs5';
</style>
```